# speed up sound using SoundPool

Tags: android, soundpool

Is it possible to make Soundpool play a sound at a faster rate, for instance play it 50% faster?

```
private void loadSound(int position, int group_position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            myVoice = soundPool.load(PhraseActivity.wr.get(), sound[group_position][0], 2);
            soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                    soundPool.play(myVoice, 20, 20, 1, 0, 1f);
                } 
            });
        break;
        case 1:
            myVoice = soundPool.load(PhraseActivity.wr.get(), sound[group_position][1], 2);
            soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                    soundPool.play(myVoice, 20, 20, 1, 0, 1f);
                } 
            });
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The playback rate allows the application to vary the playback rate (pitch) of the sound. A value of 1.0 means play back at the original frequency. A value of 2.0 means play back twice as fast, and a value of 0.5 means playback at half speed.
see [Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#play%28int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20float%29)

So you need to change 
`soundPool.play(myVoice, 20, 20, 1, 0, 1f);`
to 
`soundPool.play(myVoice, 20, 20, 1, 0, 2f);`

the value of 2 will rise the speed to 50% more as you wanted

Comment: I changed the float value to a higher - yes it speeds up but the soundfile seems to be distorted. The womans voice changes to a childs voice.

Comment: @user2365568 that's what happens when you speed up a voice.. it's a normal thing... and when you slow it down it will become heavy voice

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of `play()` controls the playback rate.

See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#play%28int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20float%29).

> **Parameters**
>
> soundID: a soundID returned by the load() function
>
> leftVolume: left volume value (range = 0.0 to 1.0)
>
> rightVolume: right volume value (range = 0.0 to 1.0)
>
> priority: stream priority (0 = lowest priority)
>
> loop: loop mode (0 = no loop, -1 = loop forever)
>
> **rate: playback rate (1.0 = normal playback, range 0.5 to 2.0)**

Note that you can only change the speed from 0.5 to 2.0, meaning half to twice as fast. Anything past that and you'll have to come up with a custom implementation.